# X and Y cannot be resolved to variable?

Tags: java, variables

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//declare a class
public class BrokenGps { 
    public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        int randomNum = ran.nextInt((max-min)+1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

//declare double variable
    public static double Firstcoordinates(double X, double Y) {
        double distance ;
        distance=Math.sqrt(X*X+Y*Y);
        return distance;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try 
    {
            double X = 0;
            double Y = 0;
            int minutelimit = 60;
            final int North = 0;
            final int South = 1;
            final int East = 2;
            final int West = 3;
            int Direction = 0;

//start loop
            while (minutelimit > 0)
                {
                if (minutelimit>=5) {
                    minutelimit -= 5;
                    Direction = randInt(0, 3);

                    if (Direction == North)
                    { 
                        Y=Y+5;
                        System.out.println("Traveled North");
                    }
                    if (Direction == South)
                    { 
                        Y= Y-5;
                        System.out.println("Traveled South");
                    }
                    if (Direction == East)
                    {
                        X=X+5;
                        System.out.println("Traveled East");
                    }
                    if (Direction == West)
                    {
                        X=X-5;
                        System.out.println("Traveled West");
                    }
                    }
                else {
                    if (Direction == North)
                    {
                        Y = Y + minutelimit * 1;
                        minutelimit = 0;
                    }
                    if (Direction == South)
                    {
                        Y = Y - minutelimit * 1;
                        minutelimit = 0;
                    }
                    if (Direction == East)
                    {
                        X = X + minutelimit * 1;
                        minutelimit = 0;
                    }
                    if (Direction == West)
                        X = X - minutelimit * 1;
                        minutelimit = 0;
                    }

                }

            }
System.out.println("The distance the car traveled in 1 hour is" + Firstcoordinates(X,Y) + "miles.");

}
    catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete BlockStatements
    X cannot be resolved to a variable
    Y cannot be resolved to a variable

```
at BrokenGps.main(BrokenGps.java:83)"
```

Not experienced enough to be able to fix the code based off of this and I am running out of time.

Comment: Please don't post [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode),  Edit your question to include your code and errors as formatted text.

Comment: @Julien Considering you're asking for our help, the least you can do is edit the question and fix it to follow the standards of this site.

Comment: If you had read the help center, as you are encouraged to, you would have seen it. ["DO NOT post images of code"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). On Stack Overflow, expect as much effort back as you have put in. In this case, not much unfortunately.

Comment: Plet put your error log.

Comment: One of the other reasons that images are discouraged is because image sites like imgur are often blocked by corporate firewalls.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Indeed. I couldn't help even if wanted to, for exactly that reason.

Comment: @Julien Believe it or not, Stack Overflow is not for you, the individual. It is about creating a repository of knowledge so that future readers can benefit. By refusing to improve your question, you are making your question useless for anyone other than you. It's selfish. We are under no obligation to help you, and if you don't make it easy for us, we simply won't. In the time that you have spent replying to comments you could have fixed it already.

Comment: what's the exact error you have?

Comment: I fixed it PLEASE help soon.

Comment: You literally have your `catch` outside of the `public static void main` block, how does your IDE not highlight this error.  Download something like Eclipse or IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

remove the `}` in the line before the `System.out` statement, that's too much